# How to get user's password?

Tags: gtk, gnome, vala

How to get user password with Vala? Secret.prompt.perform_sync() seems doesn't work.
I really don't know how use secret.prompt.

Main.vala:

```
class SecretServ : Secret.Service {
}

class SecPrompt : Secret.Prompt {
}

class ApplicationWindow : Gtk.ApplicationWindow {
    construct {
        show_all();
        var ret = new VariantType("s");
        string winid;
        winid = "%d".printf((int) this.get_id());
        
        SecPrompt prompt = new SecPrompt();
        try {
            prompt.perform_sync(winid, null, ret);
        } catch (GLib.Error e) {
            stderr.printf("ERROR: %s", e.message);
        }
    }
}

class Application : Gtk.Application {
    

    public Application() {
        Object(
            application_id: "com.github.urandom0.pass",
            flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
            );
    }

    protected override void activate() {
        ApplicationWindow window = new ApplicationWindow();
        this.add_window(window);
    }
}

static int main(string[] args) {
    var app = new Application();
    return app.run(args);
}
```

Compile:
valac Main.vala --pkg=gtk+-3.0 --pkg=libsecret-1

Run:
./Main

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please fix it so we can actually compile it. Please be more specific why the code doesn't work as well.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff
Thanks, I edited my code.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for libsecret? https://developer-old.gnome.org/libsecret/unstable/vala-examples.html

Comment: Your code shows that you don't understand the basic principles of libsecret. Why do you want to use it? Please add a description of the problem you are trying to solve with your code.

Comment: Do you want to get the UNIX password of the user? That is not what libsecret is for. It is to store and retrieve sensitive information in a password storage. The information is protected by the keyring program like gnome-keyring.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just create a Secret.Prompt like that. It is an object that is created by the libsecret library internally.

There is a Vala example on how to use libsecret here:

https://developer-old.gnome.org/libsecret/0.18/vala-examples.html

I will summarize the example as an answer below.

You have to first create a schema:

```
var example = new Secret.Schema ("org.example.Password", Secret.SchemaFlags.NONE,
                             "number", Secret.SchemaAttributeType.INTEGER,
                             "string", Secret.SchemaAttributeType.STRING,
                             "even", Secret.SchemaAttributeType.BOOLEAN);
```

Then you can store properties into the schema:

```
var attributes = new GLib.HashTable<string,string> ();
attributes["number"] = "8";
attributes["string"] = "eight";
attributes["even"] = "true";

Secret.password_storev.begin (example_schema, attributes, Secret.COLLECTION_DEFAULT,
                              "The label", "the password", null, (obj, async_res) => {
    bool res = Secret.password_store.end (async_res);
    /* ... do something now that the password has been stored */
});
```

And finally retrieve them again:

```
var attributes = new GLib.HashTable<string,string> ();
attributes["number"] = "8";
attributes["string"] = "eight";
attributes["even"] = "true";

Secret.password_lookupv.begin (example_schema, attributes, null, (obj, async_res) => {
    string password = Secret.password_lookup.end (async_res);
});
```

For more details read the whole libsecret documentation at:

https://developer-old.gnome.org/libsecret/0.18/index.html